# Resolve guard in Nativescript

Tags: angular, nativescript

I am trying to implement resolve guard for a route named 'rewards' in Nativescript but can't get it to work.

**Issue**
 - RewardListComponent is never activated if I use resolve guard in routing config - it is stuck at "ResolveStart" (please see the screenshot below) but as soon as I remove resolve guard, the component is activated just fine.

Please guide where I am going wrong here.

**Router Tracing log**

[image]

**rewards-routing.module.ts**

```js
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { NativeScriptRouterModule } from "nativescript-angular/router";

import { RewardsListResolverService } from "./services/rewards-list-resolver.service";

import { RewardsListComponent } from "./components/rewards-list/rewards-list.component";

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "rewards",
        component: RewardsListComponent,
        resolve: {
            rewards: RewardsListResolverService
        }
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [NativeScriptRouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule]
})
export class RewardsRoutingModule {}
```

**rewards.module.ts**

```js
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

import { RewardsRoutingModule } from './rewards-routing.module';
import { NativeScriptCommonModule } from 'nativescript-angular/common';
import { NativeScriptFormsModule } from 'nativescript-angular/forms';

import { RewardsService } from './services/rewards.service';
import { RewardsListResolverService } from './services/rewards-list-resolver.service';

import { RewardsListComponent } from './components/rewards-list/rewards-list.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [RewardsListComponent],
  imports: [
    RewardsRoutingModule,
    NativeScriptCommonModule,
    NativeScriptFormsModule
  ],
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
  providers: [
      RewardsService,
      RewardsListResolverService
  ]
})
export class RewardsModule { }
```

**rewards-list-resolver.service**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { SimpleReward } from '../models/simple-reward';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { RewardsService } from './rewards.service';

@Injectable()
export class RewardsListResolverService implements Resolve<SimpleReward[]> {

  constructor(private rewardsService: RewardsService) { }

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<SimpleReward[]> {
      return this.rewardsService.getAllRewards();
  }

}
```

**rewards-list.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from "@angular/core";
import { Subscription } from "rxjs";

import { SimpleReward } from '../../models/simple-reward';

@Component({
    templateUrl: "./rewards-list.component.html",
    moduleId: module.id
})
export class RewardsListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    rewards: SimpleReward[];

    private subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log('Activated');
        // this.subscribeToResolvedData();
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.subscriptions.forEach(x => x.unsubscribe());
    }
}
```

**rewards.service.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { SimpleReward } from "../models/simple-reward";

@Injectable()
export class RewardsService {

    private baseUrl = "http://10.0.2.2:52553/api/rewards";

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    getAllRewards(): Observable<SimpleReward[]> {
        const url = `${this.baseUrl}/all`;
        return this.http.get<SimpleReward[]>(url);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the implementation of `this.rewardsService.getAllRewards()`? And a side note, use `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA` if you want to have weird bugs in your app :)

Comment: Thanks for the response! I have added the implementation of Rewards service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like your service request doesn't complete, but I can't see why. You can try this, maybe this will shed some light on an error:

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<SimpleReward[]> {
  return this.rewardsService.getAllRewards().pipe(
    take(1),
    catchError((e) => {
      console.error(e);
      return of([]);
    })
  );
}
```

If that doesn't work, try to change your resolver to this:

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<SimpleReward[]> {
  return of([]);
}
```

If this does work, you can be sure that something is wrong in your service call. Are you sure it's returning a normal 200 state with an array?

Comment: Weird. I tried your first suggestion and it worked without any console error - I see the component has been activated and the resolved data(from API) is displayed. The second suggestion also worked. However, if I again change resolver to 'this.rewardsService.getAllRewards();' then the same issue shows up again - I can see in network tab that API calls returns 200.

Comment: You can keep the first solution, all it does it respond to the first response received and immediately complete. But it's weird that the http call doesn't complete. Is it some streaming http request you do there? With a HttpInterceptor or something?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out - there was an issue with HttpInterceptor I have implemented to add bearer token which was causing the GET request to never complete. I see why take(1) worked. I have fixed the bug in the interceptor and now everything works as expected. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should add providers array inside of  **rewards-routing.module.ts** and here provide your resolver.

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [NativeScriptRouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule],
    providers: [RewardsListResolverService]
})
```

Comment: I tried but the same problem. As far as I know, I don't think defining service in routing module or feature module would make any difference.

Comment: As you provide rewards.service.ts I know that you need to subscribe to the getAllRewards(). Otherwise, nothing happens.